# Custom Preference not rendering layout (xml)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-preferences

**What I want to achieve:** I want to create my own preference layout containing SeekBar and other elements and everything render in my main preference as a custom class.

**What I did:**

-I've created my own layout (which will be rendered in preferences screen). Here is basic XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

- I've created custom class which extends Preference. Here is my sample:

  public class MyCustomPreference extends Preference {

  ```
  public MyCustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);

      setLayoutResource(R.layout.mycustompreferencelayout);

  }
  ```

-I've created main preferences (which contain checkboxes and other elements, including my custom preference). Here is my sample:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Checkbox1"></CheckBoxPreference>
    <MyCustomPreference
        android:key="customKey"></MyCustomPreference>



</PreferenceScreen>
```

When I want to see my custom layout in main preferences file, I can see only checkbox and empty space where it should be my custom preference. XML says it's a render problem.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:139)
    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:105)
    at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:42)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:490)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:327)
    at android.preference.Preference_Delegate.inflatePreference(Preference_Delegate.java:60)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:320)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[image]

Obviously I'm missing something here. Official [Settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment) docs is a good read, but there is a lot of information missing.

Help would be much appriciated, because this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

use full package when custom preference class used

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBoxPreference android:title="Checkbox1"></CheckBoxPreference>
<your.full.package.MyCustomPreference
    android:key="customKey"></MyCustomPreference>
```

Now launch your App

**Note.** 
Android Studio Preview is not show your custom preference that is bug